# Basic Python. "Boolean-valued functions"

Tags: python, boolean

Here my code:

```
def my_abs(value):
    if my_abs == my_abs:            
    return (value)


print(my_abs(3.5))

print(my_abs(-7.0))
```

It prints out
3.5 and 
-7.0

But I want it to return 7.0 not with the negative symbol without using the inbuilt python abs. function.

Comment: What do you expect of `if my_abs == my_abs:`? And your code is not properly indented or seems to be missing pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_abs(value):
    if value >= 0:
        return value
    else:
        return -value


print my_abs(-7)  ##-7
print my_abs(2)  ##2
```

Or in another, more Pythonic way:

```
def my_abs(value):
    return value if value >= 0 else -value
```

Comment: Thanks! Works! Appreciate the help!